# How i can let it be a topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I have these sets $$\Omega_r=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2, (x-1)^2+(y+1)^2\geq r^2\}, r\geq0$$

I know that the set $\tau$ defined by $\varnothing$ and all $\Omega_r$  is not a topology because$$ \bigcup_{r>0}\Omega_r =\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(1,-1)\}\notin\tau$$

What must I add to $\tau$ to obtain a topology?

Thank you very much

Comment: The collection needs to be closed under arbitrary union, and you need the entire space to in the collection. Hence sets of the form $\overline{B((1,-1),r)}^c$ must be included, at least.

Comment: It might be notationally simpler to analyse the real line and sets of the form $(-\infty,-r] \cup [r,\infty)$ first?

Comment: @copper.hat  why closed ? to prove that it is a topology we need to see that the arbitrary union of open sets is open and the finite intersection of open sets is open , also i don't understand your last comment

Comment: @Vrouvrou "closed under" means that taking the [*insert set operation here*] of $\tau$ sets is still in $\tau$.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add $\Theta_r=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2\ |\ (x-1)^2+(y+1)^2> r^2\}$ for all $r\geq0$ to $\tau$ to obtain a topology $\tau_c$.

1. We easily see that $\varnothing$ and $\mathbb{R}^2=\Omega_0$ are in $\tau_c$.

As copper.hat suggested, to check the next properties, it is enough to check the radius sets $[r,\infty)$ and $(r,\infty)$ instead of $\Omega_r$ and $\Theta_r$, because the circles $x=r\cos(\phi)+1$ and $y=r\sin(\phi)-1$ are either in $\Omega_r$ (similarly for $\Theta_r$) for all $\phi$, or for none.

Note that we have the inclusions $[r,\infty)\subseteq[s,\infty)$ and $(r,\infty)\subseteq(s,\infty)$ for $r>s$.

2. For $\tau$ closed under union: suppose we have $\Omega_{a_i}$ and $\Theta_{b_j}$ with $a_i,b_j\geq 0$ for $i\in I$ and $j\in J$ (if $\varnothing$ is included then it adds nothing to the union), or equivalently $[a_i,\infty)$ and $(b_j,\infty)$ for $i\in I$ and $j\in J$. Define $s=\inf_{i\in I,j\in J}\{a_i,b_j\}$. We either have that $\bigcup_{i\in I}[a_i,\infty)\cup\bigcup_{j\in J}(b_j,\infty)=[s,\infty)$, or  we have that $\bigcup_{i\in I}[a_i,\infty)\cup\bigcup_{j\in J}(b_j,\infty)=(s,\infty)$ due to the inclusions, where $s\geq 0$ (else it wouldn't be the greatest lower bound), or equivalently we have either $\Omega_{s}=\bigcup_{i\in I}\Omega_{a_i}\cup\bigcup_{j\in J}\Theta_{b_j}$ or $\Theta_{s}=\bigcup_{i\in I}\Omega_{a_i}\cup\bigcup_{j\in J}\Theta_{b_j}$, of which both are in $\tau_c$.
3. For $\tau$ closed under finite intersection: suppose we have $\Omega_{a_i}$ and $\Theta_{b_j}$ with $a_i,b_j\geq 0$ for $i\in I$ and $j\in J$ with $I$ and $J$ finite sets (we skip $\varnothing$, as the intersection itself would trivially become $\varnothing$), or equivalently $[a_i,\infty)$ and $(b_j,\infty)$ for $i\in I$ and $j\in J$. Define $m=\max_{i\in I,j\in J}\{a_i,b_j\}$. We either have that $\bigcap_{i\in I}[a_i,\infty)\cap\bigcap_{j\in J}(b_j,\infty)=[m,\infty)$ with $m=a_k$ for some $k\in I$, or  we have that $\bigcap_{i\in I}[a_i,\infty)\cap\bigcap_{j\in J}(b_j,\infty)=(m,\infty)$ with $m=b_l$ for some $l\in J$ due to the inclusions, or equivalently we have either $\Omega_{a_k}=\bigcap_{i\in I}\Omega_{a_i}\cap\bigcap_{j\in J}\Theta_{b_j}$ or $\Theta_{b_l}=\bigcap_{i\in I}\Omega_{a_i}\cap\bigcap_{j\in J}\Theta_{b_j}$, of which both are again in $\tau_c$.

So we see that $\tau_c$ is indeed a topology containing all the elements of $\tau$ (it's the smallest one actually).

Comment: but we still have the problem of $\bigcup_{r>0}\Omega_r$ for any $r>0$ we can get $\Theta_r=\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(1,-1)\}$ ?

Comment: i also don't understand why you consider  $(r,\infty),(s,\infty),..$

Comment: @Vrouvrou $\bigcup_{r>0}\Omega_r=\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(1,-1)\}=\Theta_0\in\tau_c$, so the problem you found is solved. We consider $(r,\infty)$, because it is the radius set equivalent to $\Theta_r$ as explained under 1. After that we noted that we have the inclusions $(r,\infty)\subseteq(s,\infty)$ for $r>s$ which is equivalent to $\Theta_r\subseteq\Theta_s$.

Comment: And if we just consider $\tau=\{\emptyset, \mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(-1,1)\}\}\cup\{\Omega_r, r\geq 0\}$ it is a topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$ no?

Comment: No, because $\bigcup_{r>s}\Omega_r=\Theta_s\not\in\tau$ for any $s>0$, but it is a union of elements of $\tau$, so that $\tau$ is not a topology either.

Comment: i don't undertand the $\theta_s$ are include in $\Omega_r,r\geq0$

Comment: No, what you are saying now is that $(s,\infty)$ is included in $T=\{[r,\infty)\ |\ r\geq 0\}$, which is false. $(s,\infty)$ can be approximated by elements of $T$, but it is not in the set $T$ itself: that's why you want to add all $(s,\infty)$ too.

Comment: i don't understand what you are saying see the answer of Daniel

Comment: @Vrouvrou Do you know what polar coordinates are? Read the part of my text under 1. That explains exactly how you can use intervals instead of circles. The answer of Daniel is just my answer restated but without proof.

Answer (score 0):

It is easily seen that the intersection of any finite subset of $S=\{\phi\}\cup (\cup_{r>0}\Omega_r)$ belongs to $S$, and that (trivially ) $\phi$ and $\Bbb R^2$ belong to $S.$

But for any $t\geq 0$  the set $A(t)=\{(x,y): (x-1)^2+(y+1)^2>t\}$ is equal to the union of a subset of $S$. That is $A(t)=\cup_{u>t}\{(x,y): (x-1)^2+(y+1)^2\geq u\}.$ So a topology $T$ such that $T\supset S$ must satisfy $T\supset \{A(t):t\geq 0\}.$

It is easily shown that $U=S\cup \{A(t):t\geq 0\}$ is a topology on $\Bbb R^2. $ A finite intersection or arbitrary union of members of $U$ is either a member of $S$ or a member of $U$ \ $S=\{A(t):t\geq 0\}$.